# Pyspark select from managed table doesn't return record

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am using pyspark (visual studio code) to test the spark sql, here is my code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder \
  .master("spark:ipaddress:port") \
  .appName("spark-sql-test-app") \
  .getOrCreate()
spark.sql("create table if not exists app2 (userid int,username string) using CSV location '/tmp/spark-sql-warehouse/tables/'")

spark.sql("insert into app2 (userid,username) values (123,'alex smith')")
spark.sql("SELECT userid, username FROM db1.app2").show()
spark.sql("drop table app2 purge")
spark.stop()
```

1. create a table by using CSV
2. Insert records
3. select from the table.
   when testing the code in pyspark, there is no record return, but empty table returned:

---

```
+------+--------+  
|userid|username|
+------+--------+
+------+--------+
```

---

`spark version 3.3.2`:

1. If I run similar code in spark-sql command line, the records will be returened
2. the CSV files created sucessfuly in every working nodes under that folder, also the record is there...

**Update:**
I added 'database', but nothing help:

```
spark.sql("create database if not exists db1")
spark.sql("create table if not exists db1.app2 (userid int,username string) using CSV location '/data/spark-3.3.2/spark-sql-warehouse/tables/'")
spark.sql("insert into db1.app2 (userid,username) values (123,'alex smith')")
spark.sql("SELECT userid, username FROM db1.app2").show()
```

Comment: same result(no record return) regardless managed table or unmanaged table: for example: spark.sql("create table if not exists db1.app2 (userid int,username string)")

Comment: Always prefix your table name with the database name, make sure your didn't create your table under default directory.

Comment: Try re-running by changing table to `<database>.<table_name>`

Comment: I added database, but nothing helps...